# Use suggested correction on typo

Tags: git

I had this idea:

> When you type
>
> ```
> git glone https://repo.git
> ```
>
> you get
>
> ```
> git: 'glone' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
>
> Did you mean this?
>       clone
> ```

How can you automatically accept this suggestion for correction?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this global setting:

```
git config --global help.autoCorrect -1
```

resulting in:

```
$ git glone http://repo.git
WARNING: You called a Git command named 'glone', which does not exist.
Continuing under the assumption that you meant 'clone'
Cloning into 'repo'...
...
```